# How do I convert an RGB byte[] slice to an image.Image in go?

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, go

A C++ application running in another process passes in a char[] array of three-byte pixels (red, green, blue) to a go program. I've reconstructed this in go as a byte[] slice using cgo, but I'm unsure how to convert to an image. I can pass the width or height as well, if that is needed (I would imagine it would be).

I'm aware of the [image.RGBA](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#RGBA) type, but the documentation seems to imply that those aren't just single-byte-per-color, and that assumes that there is an alpha channel, which my very simplistic bitmap does not have. Would converting the 3 byte values I have into something that works with image.RGBA be a solution? If so, how should I do that?

Alternatively, I could do the conversion in C/C++ before sending the values into a format that go recognizes (jpeg, gif, png). Either way works for my uses, but I don't know how to approach either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Image) package is based on interfaces. Just define a new type with [those methods](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Image).

Your type's `ColorModel` would return [`color.RGBAModel`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#Model), `Bounds` - your rectangle's borders, and `At` - the color at (x, y) that you can compute if you know the image's dimensions.

Comment: That makes sense completely. I keep forgetting one of the main features of go is the ability to make your own interfaces for specific uses.